# JS file won't let me have more than two variables

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am a newbie at JS, and am trying to make my own Chrome extension with some source-free code I found on the internet. I am still learning and playing around, so some stuff is new or unknown to me, and therefore I ran into this little error. Tried to create an extension, which changes font on two Twitter accounts **but** when I try to add more than two Twitter accounts, Chrome states there was an error in one of the lines.

I have this code, which works perfectly:

```
if (link && (link.href === "https://twitter.com/Handle1" ||
             link.href === "https://twitter.com/Handle2")) {
```

If I add one, two or more handles in this part, Chrome doesn't return any errors, which I know why and it's great. It also doesn't return it in this part, if I have only two handles, like shown here:

```
if (tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle1/") === 0 ||
    tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle2/") === 0) {
```

But it returns an error, when I try to add another handle, like here:

```
if (tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle1/") === 0 ||
    tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle2/") === 0) ||
    tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle3/") === 0) {
```

Chrome says it's because of an "Unexpected token ||" but I don't know why. If it accepts two handles, and the operator is "OR", why it doesn't accept three or more handles?

Comment: parentheses problem.  `if( (...1===0) || (...2===0) || (...3===0) ) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

syntax error, one more `)` before `||`.

```
if (
  tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle1/") ===
    0 ||
  tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle2/") ===
    0 ||
  tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle3/") === 0
) {
}
```

Actually, your code can be simplified to below which might help you find where the bug is.

```js
var clickToOpenTarget = tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget;
var hrefs = [
  "https://twitter.com/Handle1/",
  "https://twitter.com/Handle2/",
  "https://twitter.com/Handle3/",
];
var hasClickToOpenTarget = hrefs.some(function (href) {
  return clickToOpenTarget.indexOf(href) === 0;
});
if (clickToOpenTarget) {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

Also, [eslint](https://eslint.org/) or [prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEBLAZgAgBSZgdzjhgDoATAQxgoGdiSwAbVMAawBUIB5ABwXYoAnAOb1UUMnAAeXdLgA6IABYwYPGkgD0mgqlVxBDCAFtNACQoTGcAIybFmAJSYAvG8wAGTAB9veQvSU1HSkTCwc3HxQAiJiEtKyCsqq6lo6+HrwhpCmFlZwAEz2IE6u7h7Ovv5EpEG09GFsnLz8QqKk4pIycpiKKmoa2rr62SbmlmTWAMzFpW4uns6gADQgEDwwqNA0yKBCghD4AApCCDsoFIz4FACeO6sARoIUbMQAyjwv4sLIMIIArnBVipjIwAOpKPRwGifMBwN5nPSoABuehuyHANHuaCgdEEMCOz2ExgoyHQlzoqwAVjQpAAhZ6vGBvCjGOAAGXEcDJFKBIBpUje32sAEV-hB4DzGJSQJ9BHiMQ8KA84IwQKseIJxDAwagyDAlMgABweDUHOhg548DGa6EGZHc1YAR3F8EJ63OIFoAFooERJGR1SBBHAXagQ4SKMTSUhydK+XRjKhfgCE8K4GKJdzY7zVtQHrr9YakAU889UMwoMIAMImEkY6EAViD-zoAge5zjMuRgIAkvFYG8wFqNgBBCRvGA3axSugAXznQA) is recommended to help you find these errors.

Comment: Thank you! I simplified the code with the example you gave me, and it gave me a little more insight in how the code works actually.

Answer (score 1):

If you reformat the problematic segment, it looks like this:

```js
if (tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle1/") === 0 ||
    tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle2/") === 0) ||
    tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle3/") === 0) {
```

However, in the second line, you can see that there's an extra `)`, which tells the JavaScript interpreter that the if statement has ended, so it throws an error when it sees an unexpected `||` immediately after the if statement.

I assume it was just a simple syntax mistake when you tried to add another clause to your if-statement. Removing this extra `)` fixes the problem:

```js
if (tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle1/") === 0 ||
    tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle2/") === 0 ||
    tweet.dataset.clickToOpenTarget.indexOf("https://twitter.com/Handle3/") === 0) {
```